# CGPoint readout inaccurate at extreme coordinates of 500,000,000

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Why can I not get an accurate readout when at extreme coordinates for CGPoint?

For example if the CGPoint created for (500000250,500000100) and I use print() I only see "5e+08" for both x and y. When I use number formatter (see below) and convert the scientific notation back to a decimal I only get 500000000 for each x and y which is 250 and 100 out of sync.

```
let coordinates = CGPointMake(500000250,500000100)

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let xCoord = numberFormatter.numberFromString("\(coordinates.x)")
let yCoord = numberFormatter.numberFromString("\(coordinates.y)")
```

I've also tried:

```
let decimalValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(coordinates.x)")
```

All the results will read out as 500000000 and the value cannot be stored for future use because it is inaccurate.

I must be missing something.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit platform? On a 32-bit platform, CGFloat is Float and has only about 6 significant digits. – Do you really have to convert the numbers to strings and back?

Comment: [Why does the resolution of floating point numbers decrease further from an origin?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23848)

Comment: Martin R: You're right, I wanted to store value in database as string but can use number instead, however if I try to convert the coordinates.x to an Int or any other number type it's inaccurate by a few points. i.e.: Int(coordinates.x) will return 500000256 instead of 500000250. I obviously don't understand how the number types work so need to do some more digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGPoint uses `CGFloat` for the x and y coordinates.

On a 32-bit platform `CGFloat` is the type `Float`, which has about 6 significant digits.  In your case the last three digits are rounded off.

If you move to a 64-bit platform `CGFloat` is the type `Double` which has at least 15 significant digits.

If you need to do calculations with 15 significant digits, do it with Double then cast to CGFloat when you pass it in to Core Graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the help David!